# Clickjacking protection using 'X-Frame-Options'?

Tags: php, html, http-headers, security

I want to add clickjacking protection to my web site using X-Frame-Options.
Several pages in my web site are shown in a frame so I want to protect them but at the same time present them properly. From what I understand I need to use the SAMEORIGIN option in the X-Frame-Options value. But what exactly does SAMEORIGIN means? Does it mean the same website? The offical description I found is not very clear regarding what does it mean that 2 pages share the same 'origin'...
Can someone here help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "origin" is a website's scheme+host+port. That is, `http://example.com/` has an origin of `(http, example.com, 80)`. `https://example.com/` is a different origin, namely `(https, example.com, 443)`.

Setting the `x-frame-options` header to `SAMEORIGIN` for a page served from `http://example.com/` means that only other pages on `http://example.com/` would be able to load that page in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Using X-Frame-Options customHeaders - add multiple uri/domains to the web.config?

solution -> add this to your web.config

```
 <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' website1.com website2.com;"/>
 </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
```